# Telescope theory used for Sound detector

Tags: acoustics

a simple arrangement that takes so many words to describe.

I am trying to make an acoustic reflector.
Because of constraints on the acquisition angle of the detector, I have designed a R1, 40cm dia parabola that collect sound waves , then  reflect the incoming sound waves to R2, a 4cm secondary parabolic reflector.

R2 will reflect the sound waves to an on-axis  detector, D1 ,through a hole in the parabala.  D1 has a limited acquisition angle of 30deg.

In this way I expect to acquire the sound waves impinging on a the area of R1 
1600 cm^2 on D1 1 cm^2 area ,  which has a limited acquisition angle, but will receive the output energy impinging on R1 1600 cm^2 area.

QUESTION:
(1) Will this design work in theory?
(2) Will is there a problem of adjusting R2 so f2 is precisely occupies the same 
    space as f1?
note the sequence of axises; incoming sound waves are parallel.
focused by R1 at f1. 
R2 reverses the process,  the sound waves reaching the focus f2 of R2 are reflected to D1 as parallel rays.

Comment: Can you include a diagram? It'd be much easier to understand. Additionally, I think that the second part of the question may be off-topic, since I interpreted it to relate to engineering. The first part (will the design work in theory) is fine.